# Parse Data Using Jenkins Groovy Pipeline Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am retrieving JSON object from a URL using `httpRequest` in a groovy script.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
      stage ('Extract Data') {
          steps {
            script {
              def response = httpRequest \
              authentication: 'user', \
              httpMode: 'GET', \
              url: "https://example.com/data"
              writeFile file: 'output.json', text: response.content

              def data = readFile(file: 'output.json')
              def details = new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(data)

              echo "Data: ${details.fields.customfield}"                                        

              }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

I am interested in the `customfield`string. The format of the string is:

```
Application!01.01.01 TestSuite1,TestSuite2,TestSuite3,TestSuite4 Product!01.01.01,Product2!01.01.02
```

I would like to parse the string into 3 data sets:

1. Map of Applications [Application: version] (there will always be one Appliction)
2. List of TestSuites [TestSuite1,...,TestSuite]
3. Map of Prodcts [Product1: version,..., ProductN: version].

However, I am not sure how to do this. 
Are there any Jenkins Groovy libraries that I can use to do this in a declarative pipeline?

**EDIT**
Based on the answer below I can see that I can make a map in the following way:

```
def applications = groups[0].split(',').collect { it.split('!') }.collectEntries { [(it):it] }
```

In the example I have:

```
application = [Application: Application]
```

How do I get:
    application = [Application: 01.01.01]

**EDIT2**
Note the following output:

```
def applications = groups[0].split(',').collect { it.split('!') }
[[Application, 01.01.01]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method. Groovy can convert the values of an Object array and convert them into a map with the `toSpreadMap()`. However, the array must have an even number of elements.

```
def appList = ['DevOpsApplication', '01.01.01']
def appMap = appList.toSpreadMap()
```

For some better answers please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898129/create-map-with-collectentries-in-groovy)

Answer (score 1):

There're no libraries I'm aware of that will have functionality to parse the data but, since you know the format of the data it's easy to parse them *manually*.

There are 3 groups in the input (`applications`, `suites`, `products`) separated by a  character. To get the groups you need:

```
def input = "Application!01.01.01 TestSuite1,TestSuite2,TestSuite3,TestSuite4 Product!01.01.01,Product2!01.01.02"
def groups = input.split(' ')
```

To process the applications you need to split group 0 with `,` character (just in case there are many applications). You got a list of pairs in format: `name!version`. Every pair must be splitted with `!`, so you get a list of lists in format: `[[name, version]]`. From the last structure it's easy to create a map. All steps together:

```
def applications = groups[0].split(',').collect { it.split('!') }.collectEntries { [(it[0]):it[1]] }
```

Getting the list of suites is easy, just split group 1 with `,` character:

```
def suites = groups[1].split(',')
```

Finally, products are analogical to the list of applications but this time group 2 should be used:

```
def products = groups[2].split(',').collect { it.split('!') }.collectEntries { [(it[0]):it[1]] }
```

Comment: Thanks. Suites are parsed correctly. But applications and products are output as `[D:e]` and `[T:E]`.

Comment: @SSF, that's correct. They're returned as maps, as you asked in your question.

Comment: Sorry my comment was wrong. they are returned as map, but only the first and second characters: I want [Application: 01.01.01], [Product:01.01.01, Product2: 01.01.02]. But I got [A:p] and [P:R]

Comment: @SSF here you have a gist: https://gist.github.com/Opalo/45b6ae9db723ad65c128e7b9b67c78eb - compare it with your code.

Comment: No unfortunately.

Comment: @SSF, you haven't copied my code literally - please see my answer once again and use the provided solution properly. I've just verified it and it works correctly.

Comment: I am not sure how you are getting the element 0 and element 1 from the list. Using `.collectEntries { [(it[0]):it[1]]` gives me character 0 and character 1 of the lists. Therefore, I end up with  [A:p] and [P:R]. As oppose to [Application: 01.01.01] for application, and  [Product:01.01.01] for products.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplifier your issue by using pipeline utility step: [readJSON](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace)

```
def data = readJSON(file: 'output.json')

echo data.fields.customfield
```

Comment: Thanks. This does not give me what I was after.