# Create Map with CollectEntries in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have the following list:
    appList = [DevOpsApplication, 01.01.01]

I would like to create a map using `collectEntries`. I know that `it` refers to the current element of an iteration (shortcut for `{ it -> it }`). Therefore, I tried to use the index:

```
def appMap = appList.collectEntries { [(it[0]):it[1]] }
```

However, this gives me:

```
[D:e, 0:1]
```

But I want `[DevOpsApplication: 01.01.01]`. Is there a way to do this?

Additionally, In future I would like this to expand to more than 2 elements (e.g. `[DevOpsApplication, 01.01.01, AnotherDevOpsApplication, 02.02.02]`) with the desired output of `[DevOpsApplication: 01.01.01, AnotherDevOpsApplication: 02.02.02]`. 
How will this be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also found another method. Groovy can convert the values of an Object array and convert them into a map with the `toSpreadMap()`. However, the array must have an even number of elements.

```
def appList = ['DevOpsApplication', '01.01.01']
def appMap = appList.toSpreadMap()
```

Comment: Good find. I think this is the most concise and therefor should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

A very short version to do this would be:

```
def appList = ["DevOpsApplication", "01.01.01"]
def appMap = [appList].collectEntries() // XXX
assert appMap == [DevOpsApplication: "01.01.01"]
```

How does it work: the function `collectEntries` takes, is expected to return a map or a two element list.  Your `appList` is already that.  So put that in another list, call `collectEntries` on it.  When no function is given to `collectEntries` it uses the identity function.

Bonus: what if `appList` has much more elements? You can use `collate` to build the tuples.

```
def appList = ["DevOpsApplication", "01.01.01", "Some", "More"]
def appMap = appList.collate(2).collectEntries() // XXX
assert appMap == [DevOpsApplication: "01.01.01", Some: "More"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You're iterating element-by-element and (because your elements are `String`-typed) mapping `0` substrings to `1` substrings.

You can use this to skip one element in each iteration and map each element at even indices to the one after it:

```
def appList = ['DevOpsApplication', '01.01.01']
def appMap = (0..(appList.size()-1)).findAll{0 == it%2}
    .collectEntries{[(appList[it]): appList[it+1]]}
```

That returns `[DevOpsApplication:01.01.01]` as expected.